# generating csv file java download on the fly

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

I have a JSP page that display information of customerrecords

There is a table display below format:

```
NAME TEL ADDRESS 
AAA 111  OREGAN
BBB 222  CAL
```

how can i create the JSP to be write to CSV and become a downloadable from the JSP page?

I would have a button download.
when the button was clicked a **customer_records_2016_04_08.csv** will be prompt to user to save the file to local drive.

I intend to use bufferwriter to write the records.
Do i need to provide a server local path to save this records temp or it can be download on the fly?

Comment: Please post what you have attempted till now?

Comment: attempt to write using bufferwriter, not sure how do i not key in a path.